# Google Play Games Services Leaderboard API, can't see other players' scores

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am developing an Android app in which I use the Google Play Games Services API.  I have successfully implemented leaderboards in every aspect except I can't see the scores of other players, only my own currently signed-in player score is shown.

It acts as if my tester users have not shared their game activity with the the current user, but in fact they have, and this fact is visilble in their accounts.  I have also confirmed that the current user shares the app with these other tester users.  UPDATE: I can see the other scores using "All", but not in "Social". Still, why aren't scores available in "Social"?

I use this GoogleApiClient:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();
```

I can switch accounts, sign-in, submit scores, etc. for each account successfully, but I simply can't see the other tester accounts scores when I start the leaderboard activity.

Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: I know this might sound silly (just making sure) - did you switch the leaderboard to show scores for "all" players (not just social). By default when you open leaderboards display they show social (i.e. the scores of people in your circles) and there is a toggle switch to show all scores.

Comment: Thanks @free3dom , I did do that, and that's the only update I have: I can see the other scores using "All", but still not using "Social". "Social" should work because each tester account is in the circle of the other, and game activity is shared with that circle.  I wonder if it's related somehow to the app not yet being published?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your app and game services backend published or still in testing mode?

Taken from Google's docs:

"Social leaderboards will initially be empty until you publish the corresponding leaderboard by using the Google Play Developer Console"

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

Another good read is: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboardsAdvanced

Comment: yes, this was the problem, thanks.  If you think the question is useful, please consider up-voting it.

Comment: Do "Social Leaderboards" include "public"? Please say yes. :)